# Limit of $\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(k^2)}{(k+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{(k^2)}{(k+1)^2}$$

What is this product?
Because of intuition I would say that this is 0, but if you expand this, you can cancel the fractions, so I was wondering, what happens at infinity?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n  \frac{(i^2)}{(i+1)^2}=\frac 1 {2^2}\cdot \frac {2^2} {3^2}\cdot \frac {3^2} {4^2}\cdot...\cdot \frac {(n-1)^2} {n^2}\cdot \frac {n^2} {n+1^2}=\frac 1 {(n+1)^2}$$

Comment: If I set n to infinity, I get zero so the value of this is zero?

Comment: @MisterSet Yes exactly!

Comment: I am not so sure. The product of non-zero terms is never zero

Comment: @sku the product is never 0 but the limit is 0, what about$ (\frac12 \cdot \frac12 \cdot ...\frac12)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\dfrac{f(i)}{f(i+1)}=\dfrac{f(1)}{f(n+1)}$$

here $f(x)=x^2$

Now set $n\to\infty$